# GitLab CI preserve environment between build stages

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am working on a python project and using [miniconda](http://conda.pydata.org/miniconda.html) to manage my environment. I am using GitLab for CI with the following runner configuration

```
stages:
  - build
  - test 

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - if hash $HOME/miniconda/bin/conda 2>/dev/null; 
      then
         export PATH="$HOME/miniconda/bin:$PATH";
      else
        wget http://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -O miniconda.sh;
        bash miniconda.sh -b -p $HOME/miniconda;
        export PATH="$HOME/miniconda/bin:$PATH";
      fi
    - conda update --yes conda

test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - conda env create --quiet --force --file environment.yml
    - source activate myenv
    - nosetests --with-coverage --cover-erase --cover-package=mypackage --cover-html
    - pylint --reports=n tests/test_final.py
    - pep8 tests/test_final.py
    - grep pc_cov cover/index.html | egrep -o "[0-9]+\%" | awk '{ print "covered " $1;}'
```

I assumed (incorrectly) that my `build` stage would setup the correct environment in which I could run my `test` stage. Looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31623924/test-after-build-would-run-in-new-environment-on-gitlab-ci) and [this GitLab issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ci-multi-runner/issues/124) I see that

> each job defined in .gitlab-ci.yml is run as separate build (where we
>   assume that there's no history)

But the alternative of lumping everything together in one stage isn't appealing

```
stages:
  - test 

test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - if hash $HOME/miniconda/bin/conda 2>/dev/null; 
      then
         export PATH="$HOME/miniconda/bin:$PATH";
      else
        wget http://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -O miniconda.sh;
        bash miniconda.sh -b -p $HOME/miniconda;
        export PATH="$HOME/miniconda/bin:$PATH";
      fi
    - conda update --yes conda
    - conda env create --quiet --force --file environment.yml
    - source activate myenv
    - nosetests --with-coverage --cover-erase --cover-package=mypackage --cover-html
    - pylint --reports=n tests/test_final.py
    - pep8 tests/test_final.py
    - grep pc_cov cover/index.html | egrep -o "[0-9]+\%" | awk '{ print "covered " $1;}'
```

The only other option I can think of is to put the environment creation steps in a [before_script](http://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/README.html#before_script) stage, but it seems redundant to continuously recreate the same environment before each stage.

Answer (score 14):

The **independence** of the jobs is a design feature. You might have noticed that GitLab's interface allows you to re-run a single job which wouldn't be possible if the jobs depended on each other.

I don't know what Miniconda exactly performs but if it builds a virtual environment in specific folders, you can use **[cache](http://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/README.html#cache)** to preserve the content of those folders between the jobs. However, you cannot fully rely on it because the documentation states that...

> The cache is provided on a best-effort basis, so don't expect that the
>   cache will be always present. For implementation details, please check
>   GitLab Runner.

Considering that your job absolutely depends on the environment being built, you would need a mechanism to detect whether the (cached) environment exists and re-create it only if needed.

I think you are taking good path trying to separate the environment setup and the jobs because it might save lots of time in case you decide one day to **run** different tests **simultaneously** (jobs at the same stage run in parallel).

Comment: Note that the warning cited above is missing from the updated documentation of Gitlab

Answer (score 9):

You can put your common commands under [before_script](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#before_script-and-after_script). It will be applied to all the of the child stages. In this way, you do not need to repeat your code.

You can use something like following:

```
stages:
  - build
  - test
  - deploy 

before_script:
  - if hash $HOME/miniconda/bin/conda 2>/dev/null; 
      then
         export PATH="$HOME/miniconda/bin:$PATH";
      else
        wget http://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -O miniconda.sh;
        bash miniconda.sh -b -p $HOME/miniconda;
        export PATH="$HOME/miniconda/bin:$PATH";
      fi
    - conda update --yes conda

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - << Your build script >>

test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - conda env create --quiet --force --file environment.yml
    - source activate myenv
    - nosetests --with-coverage --cover-erase --cover-package=mypackage --cover-html
    - pylint --reports=n tests/test_final.py
    - pep8 tests/test_final.py
    - grep pc_cov cover/index.html | egrep -o "[0-9]+\%" | awk '{ print "covered " $1;}'

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  before_script:
    - << Override to global before_script >>
    - << DO something else >>
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use [artifacts](http://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/project/builds/artifacts.html) to pass files between build stages.

However if the shared parts are environment stuff (i.e. it's not code you've written) then you probably should use a cache.